# Why do I have to install Rails every time I open a new terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, terminal

I am having a problem with Ruby On Rails. Every time I open a new terminal and type a Rails command I get this error:

```
rails --version
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.2.3 final 0
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
Exception information:

unsupported locale setting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 24, in crash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 69, in main
    enable_i18n()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 40, in enable_i18n
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/locale.py", line 541, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

The only way I can avoid this problem is to re-install Ruby and Rails, and I am a bit tired of doing it, since I have to do it every time I open a new terminal.

I tried to do a full uninstall with this command:

```
rvm implode
```

But with no success.

I also tried these commands, but still with no success:

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2 (or whatever you want your default ruby interpreter to be)
rvm gemset create rails-3.0.3
rvm use 1.9.2@rails-3.0.3 --default
gem install rails
```

Comment: Append the output of `rvm info` to your question.

Comment: how are you installing rails?

Comment: you are having a quantal problem it seems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you just need to add RVM to PATH for scripting.

Add the following lines to your ~/.bashrc file.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin/sublime_text/:$HOME/bin/cad_cuda/:$HOME/.rvm/bin
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use rvm - check the install docs and make sure that you add the code to your shell bootup process that sets up RVM when you start a new shell.

https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Look for "2. Load RVM into your shell sessions as a function"

Answer (score 0):

I used this step by step guide when I installed rails on my Ubuntu machine. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/21/set-up-an-ubuntu-local-development-machine-for-ruby-on-rails/

I can't imagine what is causing your problem, but I had some problems myself because a few dependencies came in with the wrong versions. Doing a full update might help.